# Why is JS removing elements from the original Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 dropdowns where users are going to select their top 3 choices form a pre-defined list.  I am trying to selectively remove the previously selected choice from in the subsequent dropdowns. That part seems to work, however the parent dropdown should still have all choices available.

What I am seeing is that all choices except the selected option are also removed from the first select and I can't figure out why.

I am guessing it has something to do with my limited experience with JS overall, and/or using $.push inside of a $.each but I can't figure out why.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#Field1').on('change', function() {

    var select1 = $(this).val();
    const options1 = $(this).find('option');
    var options2 = [];
    var options3 = [];

    console.log(select1);
    console.log(options1);
    
    options1.each(function(i, v) {
      if (v.value != select1) {
        options2.push(v);
      }
    });
    $('#Field2').html(options2);
  });

  $('#Field2').on('change', function() {

    var select2 = $(this).val();
    var options2 = $(this).find('option');
    var options3 = [];

    console.log(select2);
    console.log(options2);


    options2.each(function(i, v) {
      if (v.value != select2) {
        options3.push(v);
      }
    });

    $('#Field3').html(options3);
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none
}

ul li {
  margin: 25px auto;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

select {
  width: 320px;
  padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li attr="Drop_down" attrtype="select" name="q1" id="q1" class="form-q label-left form-focused"><label class="cf-label" for="Field1"><span><span>Drop-down</span></span><span class="screen-reader-legend">field type drop-down</span></label>
    <div class="cf-field">
      <select id="Field1" name="Field1" aria-labelledby="Field1" class="form-item-field cf-medium" vo="e" aria-invalid="false" data-parsley-id="11">
        <option selected="True"></option>
        <option value="choice 1" title="choice 1">choice 1</option>
        <option value="choice 2" title="choice 2">choice 2</option>
        <option value="choice 3" title="choice 3">choice 3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li attr="Drop_down_1" attrtype="select" name="q2" id="q2" class="form-q label-left"><label class="cf-label" for="Field2"><span><span>Drop-down</span></span><span class="screen-reader-legend">field type drop-down</span></label>
    <div class="cf-field">
      <select id="Field2" name="Field2" aria-labelledby="Field2" class="form-item-field cf-medium" vo="e" aria-invalid="false">
        <option selected="True"></option>
        <option value="choice 1" title="choice 1">choice 1</option>
        <option value="choice 2" title="choice 2">choice 2</option>
        <option value="choice 3" title="choice 3">choice 3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li attr="Drop_down_2" attrtype="select" name="q3" id="q3" class="form-q label-left"><label class="cf-label" for="Field3"><span><span>Drop-down</span></span><span class="screen-reader-legend">field type drop-down</span></label>
    <div class="cf-field">
      <select id="Field3" name="Field3" aria-labelledby="Field3" class="form-item-field cf-medium" vo="e" aria-invalid="false">
        <option selected="True"></option>
        <option value="choice 1" title="choice 1">choice 1</option>
        <option value="choice 2" title="choice 2">choice 2</option>
        <option value="choice 3" title="choice 3">choice 3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Because you're **moving** elements, not **copying** them.

Comment: @KevinB - Would that be because I am passing in the option object into my options2 array?

Comment: options2.push(v); This line is your reason. You are moving them, not copying.

Comment: That's part of the problem, though the actual moving occurs when you call .html

Comment: OK, I will give it another go and refactor it removing some of the complexity that @APAD1 suggested.  Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the comments have said, an issue you were having was *moving* the elements, rather than *copying* them. I've used jQuery's `.clone()` to make a copy of the elements before moving them, so we can preserve the options in `$('#Field1')`

---

I've also added a function bound to the other selects `$('select[id!="Field1"]')` that will make sure the placeholder text is removed when their value is updated.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Field1').on('change', function () {
        // Change name to add readability
        let value = $(this).val();
    
        // Find the options with a value attribute that isn't the selected
        let $option = $(this).find(`option[value!="${value}"]`).clone();
    
        $('select').not(this).html($option);
    });

    $('#Field2').on('change', function () {
        let value = $(this).val();
        let $option = $(this).find(`option[value!="${value}"]`);

        $('#Field3').html($option);
    });
  
    // Removing the other options from Fields2 + Fields3 once they're selected
    $('select[id!="Field1"]').change(function () {
        let value = $(this).val();
        $(this).find(`option[value!="${value}"]`).hide();
    });
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
  
  margin: 25px auto;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

select {
  width: 320px;
  padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li attr="Drop_down" attrtype="select" name="q1" id="q1" class="form-q label-left form-focused"><label class="cf-label" for="Field1"><span><span>Drop-down</span></span><span class="screen-reader-legend">field type drop-down</span></label>
    <div class="cf-field">
      <select id="Field1" name="Field1" aria-labelledby="Field1" class="form-item-field cf-medium" vo="e" aria-invalid="false" data-parsley-id="11">
        <option selected="True"></option>
        <option value="choice 1" title="choice 1">choice 1</option>
        <option value="choice 2" title="choice 2">choice 2</option>
        <option value="choice 3" title="choice 3">choice 3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li attr="Drop_down_1" attrtype="select" name="q2" id="q2" class="form-q label-left"><label class="cf-label" for="Field2"><span><span>Drop-down</span></span><span class="screen-reader-legend">field type drop-down</span></label>
    <div class="cf-field">
      <select id="Field2" name="Field2" aria-labelledby="Field2" class="form-item-field cf-medium" vo="e" aria-invalid="false">
        <option selected="True"></option>
        <option value="choice 1" title="choice 1">choice 1</option>
        <option value="choice 2" title="choice 2">choice 2</option>
        <option value="choice 3" title="choice 3">choice 3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li attr="Drop_down_2" attrtype="select" name="q3" id="q3" class="form-q label-left"><label class="cf-label" for="Field3"><span><span>Drop-down</span></span><span class="screen-reader-legend">field type drop-down</span></label>
    <div class="cf-field">
      <select id="Field3" name="Field3" aria-labelledby="Field3" class="form-item-field cf-medium" vo="e" aria-invalid="false">
        <option selected="True"></option>
        <option value="choice 1" title="choice 1">choice 1</option>
        <option value="choice 2" title="choice 2">choice 2</option>
        <option value="choice 3" title="choice 3">choice 3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you.  This doesn't seem to work the way I expected.  Select #1 should always all choices available so that the user can change their mind.  When I test your solution, I am still only left with selected choice as the only option for Select #1.

Comment: Yes, after I posted this I saw the comment on APAD1's answer - I'm currently making some adjustments to this. Sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code quite a bit by not targeting each select individually.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('li:first-child select').on('change', function(){
    // Clear previous selections
    $('select').not(this).val('default');
    
    // Get selected option
   var selected = $(this).val();
    
    // Enable subsequent select dropdowns
    $('select').attr('disabled',false);
    
    // Show all select options
    $('select option').show();
    // Hide option selected in first dropdown
    $('select').not(this).find($('option[value="' + selected + '"]')).hide();
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type:none
}

ul li {
  
  margin: 25px auto;
}

label {
  display:block;
  margin-bottom:12px;
}

select {
  width:320px;
  padding:6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li attr="Drop_down" attrtype="select" name="q1" id="q1" class="form-q label-left form-focused">
      <label class="cf-label" for="Field1"><span><span>Drop-down</span></span><span class="screen-reader-legend">field type drop-down</span></label>
      <div class="cf-field">
         <select id="Field1" name="Field1" aria-labelledby="Field1" class="form-item-field cf-medium" vo="e" aria-invalid="false" data-parsley-id="11">
            <option selected disabled>Make a selection</option>
            <option value="choice 1" title="choice 1">choice 1</option>
            <option value="choice 2" title="choice 2">choice 2</option>
            <option value="choice 3" title="choice 3">choice 3</option>
         </select>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li attr="Drop_down_1" attrtype="select" name="q2" id="q2" class="form-q label-left">
      <label class="cf-label" for="Field2"><span><span>Drop-down</span></span><span class="screen-reader-legend">field type drop-down</span></label>
      <div class="cf-field">
         <select id="Field2" name="Field2" aria-labelledby="Field2" class="form-item-field cf-medium" vo="e" aria-invalid="false" disabled>
            <option value="default" selected disabled>Make a selection</option>
            <option value="choice 1" title="choice 1">choice 1</option>
            <option value="choice 2" title="choice 2">choice 2</option>
            <option value="choice 3" title="choice 3">choice 3</option>
         </select>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li attr="Drop_down_2" attrtype="select" name="q3" id="q3" class="form-q label-left">
      <label class="cf-label" for="Field3"><span><span>Drop-down</span></span><span class="screen-reader-legend">field type drop-down</span></label>
      <div class="cf-field">
         <select id="Field3" name="Field3" aria-labelledby="Field3" class="form-item-field cf-medium" vo="e" aria-invalid="false" disabled>
            <option value="default" selected disabled>Make a selection</option>
            <option value="choice 1" title="choice 1">choice 1</option>
            <option value="choice 2" title="choice 2">choice 2</option>
            <option value="choice 3" title="choice 3">choice 3</option>
         </select>
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, but from testing your suggestion this also removes the original options form the first select when you make the 3rd selection.  Basically the users can change their mind at some point and we have to start over from the first dropdown.

Comment: Ok, so basically you want the first dropdown to always have 3 options and then the subsequent dropdowns will always have the 2 options not selected in the first dropdown?

Comment: I have updated it. I am assuming you want the user to make their selection in the first dropdown first, so I have the other two disabled by default. Then when a selection is made, the subsequent select dropdowns are enabled and the option selected in the first dropdown is hidden from them. Then if the option in the first dropdown changes, the new selected option is hidden from the others. Let me know if that's what you had in mind.

Comment: Why do the previous values have to be set to default? // Clear previous selections

Comment: @Remi Because if the user changes their mind and changes their selection in the first dropdown, that option would remain selected in either of the subsequent dropdowns, despite it being hidden. If you comment that line out and then select "choice 1" in the first dropdown and "choice 2" in the second dropdown and then go back and change the first dropdown to "choice 2," you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

From a UX perspective, rather than removing the option from the select field you could also make it disabled. That way the user will know that it still is an option to change it.

Also you wouldn't have to mutate the entire select field when populating it with the new options. Just disable the option that was already chosen. This makes it scalable since you can add as many select fields as you wish.

The following code just loops over them all. And then disables the option the which is the same as the previously selected option from all select fields. This will enable you to choose the fields at random, so you wouldn't necessarily have to start at the first select field.

You could now also add options specific to a select field which are not affected.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // only target select fields inside #select-wrapper
  const selectFields = $('#select-wrapper').find('select');
  selectFields.on('change', function(){
    const thisSelect = $(this);
    // for all other fields that the changed field
    selectFields.not(thisSelect).each((i, selectField) => {
      // loop through options
      $(selectField).find('option').each((i, option) => {
        // if option value is the same as selected option value disable it
   if (option.value === thisSelect[0].value) {
        $(option).prop('disabled', true);
        }
        // if there is an oldValue
        if (thisSelect.attr('oldValue') && option.value === thisSelect.attr('oldValue')) {
          // enable it again on each select option
          $(option).prop('disabled', false);
        }
      });
    });
    // set the old value to make enabling it again possible
    $(this).attr('oldValue', thisSelect.val());
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none
}

ul li {
  margin: 25px auto;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

select {
  width: 320px;
  padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="select-wrapper">
  <li attr="Drop_down" attrtype="select" name="q1" id="q1" class="form-q label-left form-focused"><label class="cf-label" for="Field1"><span><span>Drop-down</span></span><span class="screen-reader-legend">field type drop-down</span></label>
    <div class="cf-field">
      <select id="Field1" name="Field1" aria-labelledby="Field1" class="form-item-field cf-medium" vo="e" aria-invalid="false" data-parsley-id="11">
        <option selected="True"></option>
        <option value="choice 1" title="choice 1">choice 1</option>
        <option value="choice 2" title="choice 2">choice 2</option>
        <option value="choice 3" title="choice 3">choice 3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li attr="Drop_down_1" attrtype="select" name="q2" id="q2" class="form-q label-left"><label class="cf-label" for="Field2"><span><span>Drop-down</span></span><span class="screen-reader-legend">field type drop-down</span></label>
    <div class="cf-field">
      <select id="Field2" name="Field2" aria-labelledby="Field2" class="form-item-field cf-medium" vo="e" aria-invalid="false">
        <option selected="True"></option>
        <option value="choice 1" title="choice 1">choice 1</option>
        <option value="choice 2" title="choice 2">choice 2</option>
        <option value="choice 3" title="choice 3">choice 3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li attr="Drop_down_2" attrtype="select" name="q3" id="q3" class="form-q label-left"><label class="cf-label" for="Field3"><span><span>Drop-down</span></span><span class="screen-reader-legend">field type drop-down</span></label>
    <div class="cf-field">
      <select id="Field3" name="Field3" aria-labelledby="Field3" class="form-item-field cf-medium" vo="e" aria-invalid="false">
        <option selected="True"></option>
        <option value="choice 1" title="choice 1">choice 1</option>
        <option value="choice 2" title="choice 2">choice 2</option>
        <option value="choice 3" title="choice 3">choice 3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```